# How do I set a JNDI variable in JBOSS?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I'm using JBoss 5.1 and I want to specify the location of my configuration files as a JNDI entry so I can look it up in my web application.  How can I go about doing this properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two main ways to do this.

**Deployment Descriptor / Declarative**

Use the [JNDI Binding Manager](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Additional_Naming_MBeans-JNDI_Binding_Manager.html) by creating a deployment descriptor in a file such as *my-jndi-bindings***-service.xml** and drop it into the server's **deploy** directory. An example descriptor looks like this:

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr" 
       name="jboss.tests:name=example1">
    <attribute name="BindingsConfig" serialDataType="jbxb">
        <jndi:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                       xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service"
                       xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service  \
               resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd"> 
            <jndi:binding name="bindexample/message">
                <jndi:value trim="true">
                    Hello, JNDI!
                </jndi:value>
            </jndi:binding>
        </jndi:bindings>
    </attribute>
</mbean>
```

**Programatic**

Acquire a JNDI context  and execute the binding yourself. This is an example of an "in-jboss" call to do this:

```
import javax.naming.*;

    public static  void bind(String name, Object obj) throws NamingException {
        Context ctx = null;
        try {
            ctx = new InitialContext();
            ctx.bind(name, obj);
        } finally {
            try { ctx.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
```

If the name is already bound, you can call **rebind**:

```
public static  void rebind(String name, Object obj) throws NamingException {
    Context ctx = null;
    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext();
        ctx.rebind(name, obj);
    } finally {
        try { ctx.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

To remove the binding, call **unbind**:

```
public static  void unbind(String name) throws NamingException {
    Context ctx = null;
    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext();
        ctx.unbind(name);
    } finally {
        try { ctx.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

If you're trying to do this remotely  (ie. not in the JBoss VM) then you will need to acquire a remote JNDI context:

```
import javax.naming.*;
String JBOSS_JNDI_FACTORY = "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory";
String JBOSS_DEFAULT_JNDI_HOST = "localhost";
int JBOSS_DEFAULT_JNDI_PORT = 1099;
.....
Properties p = new Properties();
p.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JBOSS_JNDI_FACTORY);
p.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, JBOSS_DEFAULT_JNDI_HOST + ":" + JBOSS_DEFAULT_JNDI_PORT);
Context ctx = new InitialContext(p);
```